# Удаление функций C++

Tags: c++, функции

Если функция является зарезервированным набором команд в памяти, то могу ли я её удалить? Если да, то как?

Comment: Зачем Вам это нужно?

Comment: Вы можете модифицировать функцию, которую хотите удалить?

Comment: можете удалить и функцию и файл, где она обьявлена.  Но не подскажете в каком случаи это может быть нужно?...

Comment: Возможно, некорректный перевод английского оборота `Deleted functions` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions , который вовсе не удаляет функцию, а запрещает ее вызов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Удалить функцию (кусок кода, то есть зарезервированный набор команд в памяти) из этой самой памяти вполне возможно. Но, как тут уже справедливо указали коллеги, таких механизмов непосредственно в языке С++ не предусмотрено. К счастью, такие механизмы обычно предусмотрены в операционных системах. В частности, во всеми любимой операционной системе Windows, предусмотрен механизм загрузки и выгрузки так называемых dll (dynamic link library).

Таким образом, если Вам надо попользоваться функцией, а потом удалить ее из памяти, то Вы должны (для OC Windows):

1. Поместить функцию в dll (создать dll)
2. Загрузить эту dll в своем приложении с помощью LoadLibrary
3. Получить адрес функции с помощью GetProcAddress
4. Поработать с функцией (вызвать ее)
5. Выгрузить dll с помощью  FreeLibrary

UPD1:

Тут коллеги спрашивают, зачем может понадобится удалять часть кода из памяти. Конечно, по нынешним временам мы избалованы изобилием ОЗУ и забыли страшное слово "оверлеи", хорошо знакомое тем, кто начинал во времена MS DOS. Но вполне можно представить себе ситуацию и сейчас, когда кода много, а используется он в режиме или/или. То есть после запуска программы и выбора режима работы пользователем приложение загружает нужную DLL и работает. После окончания работы DLL выгружается и приложение ждет выбора нового режима работы.

UPD2:

В связи с этим возникает интересный вопрос о фрагментации уже не кучи, а фрагментации области кода (по аналогии с фрагментацией кучи). Вполне возможно представить себе ситуацию, когда после долгой работы много загруженных и выгруженных маленьких DLL разобъют область кода на части и система не сможет загрузить большую DLL, несмотря на то, что общий размер свободной области будет превышать размер большой DLL.

Comment: А при чем сдесь динамическая загрузка библиотек?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch Просто DLL это законный метод как удалить часть кода (функцию) из памяти. О чем, собственно, и был вопрос.

Comment: только врят ли выгрузку библиотеки можно назвать удалением, тем более конкретной функции. Хотя тут скорее вопрос не конкретен

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch Да не вопрос. Вообще удалю. :-)

Answer (score 2):

С точки зрения языка C++ — нет, такого механизма не предусмотрено.

С точки зрения большинства реализаций — это гипотетически возможно, в зависимости от того что именно понимать под термином «удалить функцию», но довольно сложно и не имеет за собой особого практического смысла. Общая идея состоит в том чтобы во время исполнения затереть или заменить на заглушку область памяти на которую ссылается функция. т.к на большинстве современных платформ область памяти с исполняемым кодом защищена от записи, то придётся аллоцировать новую область память, копировать туда содержимое текущей, изменяя нужный участок, а потом переподключать её по старым адресам.